# Using torch.compile twice on a model on the same machine, is there a cache of optimized operations?

Tags: pytorch

I'm using torch.compile to compile a torch model by:

```
self.model = torch.load(saved_model_path, map_location=self.device).to(self.device)
self.model.eval()

self.model.half()

# Configure hidet to use tensor core and enable tuning
hidet.torch.dynamo_config.use_tensor_core(True)
hidet.torch.dynamo_config.search_space(2)
self.model = torch.compile(self.model, backend="hidet")
```

I ran this on a remote machine a first time. Lots of optimization operations were being skipped because they weren't supported:

```
[2024-02-03 12:48:24,408] torch._dynamo.convert_frame: [WARNING]     raise NotImplementedError("\n".join(lines))
[2024-02-03 12:48:24,408] torch._dynamo.convert_frame: [WARNING] torch._dynamo.exc.BackendCompilerFailed: backend='hidet' raised:
[2024-02-03 12:48:24,408] torch._dynamo.convert_frame: [WARNING] NotImplementedError: The following modules/functions are not supported by hidet yet:
[2024-02-03 12:48:24,408] torch._dynamo.convert_frame: [WARNING]   torch.nn.AvgPool3d
```

but many others were. After a while, the optimizations were done and inference was performed.

Then, I ran it again on the same machine, but I only saw the warnings regarding the skipped operations. Why is that? Is there some sort of cache, so that optimizations are not performed again for the same model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `torch._dynamo.reset()`
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torch_compile_tutorial.html

Which is recommended to use when using a different mode.

There was also `torch._dynamo.reset_code_caches` recently added:
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/main/torch/_dynamo/__init__.py#L83